# set column width in word automation throws an exception

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-word, vsto, word-automation

I'm using Word automation to construct a table, I need one column to be very narrow but every time I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Column.SetWidth method to set the width, it throws "value out of range Exception"
it works if I make it a larger value but it is critical to be as small as it could get

someone suggested that the spacing and padding be set to zero, which I did, but it still throws the exception

```
      table.LeftPadding = 0;
      table.RightPadding = 0;
      table.Spacing = 0;
      table.Columns[4].SetWidth(9f, WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustNone);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SetWidth` take parameter in points. Try this

```
table.Columns[4].SetWidth(
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.MillimetersToPoints(9f), 
    WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustNone);
```

or use this

```
table.Columns[4].PreferredWidth = 9f;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the example is in points not millimeters, the preferred width property throws out of range exception as well :(

Comment: Set this table.Columns[4].PreferredWidthType = WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPoints;

Comment: dirty way to make SetWidth() is to convert points to millimeters and use the code above.